# How to change working directory for calculation and save

Tags: export, files-and-directories

I'm having a problem setting the working directory. I want to do some computation and save my data at one location (D), but in the code below you can see that mathematica shifts automatically to a different location (C). How to use D partition for calculating if mathematica is installed on C?

When I run the code shown below, the file is saved on D but first it is saved on C and on C I don't have enough space.

```
  In[7]:= ResetDirectory[] 


  "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents"

  In[8]:= DirectoryStack[]

  Out[8]= {}

  In[10]:= SetDirectory["D:\\"]

  Out[10]= "D:\\"

  A:=5;

  Export["A.wdx", A];

  In[13]:= DirectoryStack[] 

  {"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents"}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$TemporaryDirectory`?

Comment: Can you change `SetDirectory["D:\\"]` to `SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory]` and rerun the whole program?

Comment: As reality check, have a look if and where "A.wdx" is in fact saved...?

Answer (score 6):

The [Documentation page for `ResetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ResetDirectory.html) says under "MORE INFORMATION" field:

> Successive calls to `ResetDirectory` yield earlier and earlier current
>   directories.
>
> `ResetDirectory` uses the directory stack given by `DirectoryStack[]`.
>
> `ResetDirectory` removes the last element from the directory stack,
>   and makes the second-to-last element current.

And [the page for `DirectoryStack[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DirectoryStack.html) says:

> Each call to `SetDirectory` prepends one element to the directory stack;
>   each call to `ResetDirectory` drops one.

So it is not surprizing that `DirectoryStack[]` initially is a blank list. The call to `SetDirectory` adds to this list one element: previous working directory. To get the current working directory you should evaluate [`Directory[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directory.html).

Answer (score 2):

The exact code  (I also happen to have a D partition:)  runs fine on my computer (Win7, mma 8). The file is created in D:\, just the output of `DirectoryStack` is misleading. I don't really know, why it doesn't include D:\

You can check your current working directory using `Directoy`.

```
ResetDirectory[]

(* ==> "E:\\Projekti\\MD\\SCRIPTS\\mathematica\\FitSpectra" *)

DirectoryStack[]

(* ==> {"C:\\Users\\ajasja\\Documents"} *)

SetDirectory["D:\\"]

(* ==> "D:\\" *)

A := 5;

Export["A.wdx", A];

DirectoryStack[]

(*
==> {"E:\\Projekti\\MD\\SCRIPTS\\mathematica\\FitSpectra", \
"C:\\Users\\ajasja\\Documents"}
*)

Directory[]

(* ==> "D:\\" *)
```